# Eliminar elemento de un array

Tags: java, array, poo, netbeans, class

He implementado este código para eliminar un registro de un array de objetos.

```
public boolean eliminarVehiculo (String matricula) {            // MÉTODO PARA ELIMINAR UN VEHÍCULO DEL ARRAY.
    
    boolean eliminarVehiculo = false;
    
    Vehiculo[] cochesBackup = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < coches.length-1; i ++) {
        if (coches[i].getMatricula().equals(matricula)) {
            cochesBackup = new Vehiculo[coches.length - 1];
            for (int index = 0; index < i; index ++) {
                cochesBackup[index] = coches[index];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < coches.length - 1; j++) {
                cochesBackup[j] = coches[j + 1];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    
    coches = null;
    
    coches = cochesBackup;
    
    cochesBackup = null;
    
    numCoches--;
    
    return eliminarVehiculo;
}               // FIN DEL MÉTODO eliminarVehiculo.
```

Sólo me borra el primer elemento.

He intentado buscar ese elemento en el array, y copiar lo que hay antes y después de ese elemento buscado en un array nuevo. Luego he vaciado el array que utilizo y lo he vuelto a llenar con la copia del nuevo array.

Answer (score 1):

Un Array es un objeto contenedor que contiene un número fijo de valores de un solo tipo. La longitud de una matriz se establece cuando se crea la matriz. Después de la creación, su longitud es fija.

Fuente:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

si lo que buscas es agregar buscar o eliminar existen otras clases,como la clase **ArrayList** que contienen  métodos como remove(eliminar)y add(agregar) los cuales te facilitan un poco la metodología de POO,un ArrayList empieza como una carpeta vacía en la que tu vas agregando documentos y posteriormente puedes eliminarlos, extraerlos o copiarlos etc.(claro que hay restricciones)..

Fuente:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

te comparto un Ejemplo en base a tu pregunta,espero te sirva

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
private List<Vehiculo> concesionario;
public Test(){
    this.concesionario=new ArrayList<>(50);
    //se puede declarar el limite del arraylist
}
public int insertarVehiculo(String marca,String matricula){
    int valorDevuelto=0;
     //size devuelve el tamaño de la lista como un lenght en un array
     if(concesionario.size()==0){// si la lista osea el concecionario esta vacio devuelve -1
           valorDevuelto=-1;
     }
     if(existe(matricula)){//usamos el metodo existe para saber si dentro de nuestra lista
     //existe un vehiculo con la matricula que intentamos registrar si es asi devuelve -2 
         valorDevuelto=-2;
     }
    if(concesionario.size()!=0&&existe(matricula)==false){
    //si la lista ya no esta vacia y no existe un vehiculo con la matricula pasamos a registrar
    //un nuevo vehiculo y usamos add para agregar a nuesta lista el nuevo vehiculo  
       Vehiculo vehiculo=new Vehiculo();
       vehiculo.setMarca(marca);
       vehiculo.setMatricula(matricula);
       this.concesionario.add(vehiculo);
       valorDevuelto=0;
    }

   return valorDevuelto;
}

public void registrarVehiculos(String marca,String matricula){
//Metodo que registra vehiculos
       Vehiculo vehiculo=new Vehiculo();
       vehiculo.setMarca(marca);
       vehiculo.setMatricula(matricula);
       this.concesionario.add(vehiculo);
}

public boolean existe(String matricula){
   //Metodo en el que comprobamos si existe un vehiculo con una matricula repetida
    for(Vehiculo v:concesionario){
       if(v.getMatricula().equals(matricula)){
             return true; 
       }
    }return false;
}

public void eliminarVehiculo(String matricula){
    //buscamos un vehiculo con una matricula dad y la eliminamos de nuestra lista
    for(Vehiculo v:concesionario){
      if(v.getMatricula().equals(matricula)){
           concesionario.remove(v);
      }
    }
}
public List<Vehiculo> getConcesionario() {
    return concesionario;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test=new Test();

    //al inicio la lista estara vacia
    System.out.println(test.insertarVehiculo("Toyota","AKJ-542"));//devuelve -1
    //como el metodo insertar se basa en condicionales if no nos permitira registrar
    //un nuevo vehiculo hasta que nuesta lista tengo al menos un dato
    test.registrarVehiculos("Nissan","AKJ-543");//usamos el metodo registrar para agregar un nuevo vehiculo
    System.out.println(test.insertarVehiculo("Toyota","AKJ-543"));//devuelve-2 por duplicidad
    System.out.println(test.insertarVehiculo("Toyota","AKJ-544"));//devuelve 0
    System.out.println(test.insertarVehiculo("Volkswagen","AKJ-545"));//devuelve 0
    //imprimimos la lista
    List<Vehiculo>lista=test.getConcesionario();
    int i=0;
for(Vehiculo v:lista){
       System.out.println("\nAuto # "+(i+1)+"\nMarca: "+v.getMarca()+"\nMatricula: "+v.getMatricula()+"\n");
       i++;


    }
}

}
```

Comment: Con un ArrayList, como me dijiste en unos días, funciona pero creo que el ejercicio que me mandan es con un Array porque aún no hemos visto los ArrayList. Por eso estoy intentandolo hacer con un Array.

Comment: @Pozo https://www.codiva.io/p/83c9ca48-9c17-400b-80f0-2ca57f927b3e

Comment: Gracias!!! Al final he estado investigando y lo he conseguido hacer porque tu forma de hacerlo me daba problemas. Aún así muchísimas gracias!!